# Very strange behavior comparing string property in node js (vs-code)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

this is from debug console:

```
a[0]
"15711"
a[0] == "15711"
"false"
parseInt(a[0]) == 15711
"true"
```

Can someone explain this?

the "a" property is one of the rows that i read from csv file  with fast-csv.
this is the code :

```
    var fs = require('fs')
    var path = require('path')
    var csv = require('fast-csv');
    var all = [];
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(path.join("./items.txt"));

    var csvStream = csv({ delimiter: '\t' })
        .on("data", function (data) {
           console.log(data[0] == '1')
        })
        .on("end", function () {

        })

    stream.pipe(csvStream);
```

[the repo](https://github.com/yantrab/compare-string-node-js)

Comment: what is typeof a[0] ? Are you sure it's not a getter function?

Comment: typeof a[0]
"string"

Comment: Ok can you post your full code and data somewhere? I can't seen to find no reason for your comparison to be behaving like that for the moment.

Comment: I edited my question. just put 1 in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok with your example on the repo that had a CSV with just the value of 1. You can see the length of this "1" char is actually 2 (the expected would be 1).
The first char of the first String is an invisible char.
I did a :

```
data[0].charCodeAt(0)
```

To check which char would that be. It gave me the value 65279 which is a [Zero width no break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm). This character is the [BOM](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom1) from UTF8 encoded streams.
There is an open issue on the project you are using regarding this ([here](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv/issues/131)).

Since this is a space char we could remove it with [trim()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) and have the comparisons behaving normally.

Or using the solution to strip the BOM from the pipe like the guy from the issue did, using the [strip-bom-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strip-bom-stream) package.

Comment: WOW, thank you for the answer. so, the unexpected behavior belongs to fs, or to fastcsv?

Comment: I would say fast csv. Using their library I wouldn't expect a behavour like that. If you use just fs.readStream you would indeed get the same behavour but since you are dealing with binary data wouldn't be strange to ask for you to be aware of that. In my opinion the library is the one that breaking the principle of least surprise